# add column after selected one

Tags: postgresql

i m using postgres, i want to add column "call" after column "script"... so any query that will help me....

Comment: The order of the columns in a table is completely irrelevant (just like the order of rows in a table). So why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: Yeah but you can sort the rows for aesthetic effect.  Why shouldn't you be able to order the columns the way you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not possible. Unless you drop the table and create a new one with all columns in the required order.

The SQL Standard don't have an order for columns anyway.

Comment: And what would be "the disadvantage" ? There is no order in columns anyway, it doesn't matter for performance or any query plan at all.

Comment: Certainly the SQL standard has provisions for a column order.

Comment: Hmmm, I must have missed it :-(